# Unknown property 'extra' when migrating to Kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm having a headache converting Groovy to Kotlin DSL. I get the following error on `project level` `build.gradle` on `extra.apply`:

```
Could not get unknown property 'extra' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.
```

The following is my `gradle` code:

```
buildscript {
    extra.apply{
        // App dependencies
        set("rxjava2Version", "2.1.9")
        set("rxandroidVersion", "2.1.1")
        set("butterKnifeVersion", "10.1.0")
        set("kotlinVersion", "1.8.0")
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproduced example and descrive version of gradle?

Answer (score 0):

`buildscript` does not provide `extra`. `extra` or extra properties is provided by types that implement `ExtensionAware` which `buildscript` does not.

In your case, what you really want is any one of the following:

```
extra["rxjava2Version"] = "2.1.9"
val rxandroidVersion by extra { "2.1.1" }
```

Which is placed *outside* of the `buildscript { }` and in your Gradle file directly where `this` refers to `project`.